# How to create an cpp program that when executed it doesn't show any windows

Tags: c++, windows

I'm running this code, it's a simple code to lock Windows 8 screen on a Dell that has a button that can be assigned to a `.exe`, but it shows a `cmd` window before locking, how can I launch the `.exe` without showing the window?

Compiling using Visual Studio Dev Command Prompt

Command Line:

```
cl lockscreen.cpp
```

Code:

```
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int APIENTRY  WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
        HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
        LPTSTR    lpCmdLine, 
        int       cmdShow)
{

    system("rundll32 user32.dll,LockWorkStation");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what would you like to launch instead?

Comment: Isn't the Win+L shortcut good enough?

Answer (score 3):

Link against user32.dll (user32.lib actually, the import library, but you should already be doing that if this is a stock win32 project) and just *invoke* `LockWorkstation` directly. If you must, `LoadLibrary`() + `GetProcAddress`() + etc.. There is no need for you to invoke a rundll call for this to work.

Comment: and use the `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` linker option, because console applications will always show a console window when started

Comment: @BenVoigt Assuming he was already there, or he wouldn't link, as _main would be an undefined symbol. The console is popping from the `system()` call.

Answer (score 2):

Basically I agree with WhozCraig, but if there is a good reason to make the call via an external exe, try calling it with `start /b`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to compile any code at all. Just connect your special keyboard button to

```
rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation
```